# Ember.Component.set doesn't update template

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which displays a value from a object.
This object gets loaded with `Ember.$.ajax` into `strings`

Because `strings` is loaded asynchronously and/or can change at runtime (not in this example), I use `.done()` to get the value I need.

A simple template does work

```
{{u-string name="test_value"}}
```

But if nest `{{u-string}}` with an component which `{{yield}}`s,
it won't update the template.

```
 {{#u-button}}
     {{u-string name="test_btn"}}
 {{/u-button}}
```

Here is my simplified component code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var strings = Ember.$.ajax({
        url: '/api/strings'
    });

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    value: '?',
    count: null,

    willInsertElement: function() {
        console.log("Strings wait for \"" + this.get('name') + "\"");
        strings.done((value) => {
            Ember.run(() => { 
                var s = value[this.get('name')] || this.get('name');
                console.log("Strings got \"" + s + "\" for \"" + this.get('name') + "\"");
                this.set('value', s);
            });
        }); 
    }
});
```

Here is my `{{u-string}}` template:

```
{{value}}
```

If I `transitionTo` it will display the text correctly, but when I visit the page directly (or refresh) it will not.
Based on the `console.log` and debugging, the `value` gets set correctly but the template doesn't update.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or should this work ?
Is it even possible to use `this` later (via an async callback) ?
If not how would I update my components value ?

Comment: Are there any exceptions/errors in the console when you use the above code?

Comment: @Isowen there are no errors/exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is not with the overall function of your code from an Ember standpoint, but rather that `this` within your `Ember.run()` portion of `willInsertElement` doesn't refer to the component.

You have two ways to deal with this:

1. Use a placeholder variable (usually `self`) to hold the value of `this` which can be accessed inside the other "inner" functions.
2. Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to change what `this` refers to.

Option 1:

```
willInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("Strings wait for \"" + this.get('name') + "\"");
    strings.done(function (value){
        Ember.run(function(){ 
             var s = value[self.get('name')] || self.get('name');
            console.log("Strings got \"" + s + "\" for \"" + self.get('name') + "\"");
            self.set('value', s);
        });
    }); 
}
```

Option 2:

```
willInsertElement: function() {
    console.log("Strings wait for \"" + this.get('name') + "\"");
    strings.done(function (value){
        Ember.run(function(){ 
             var s = value[this.get('name')] || this.get('name');
            console.log("Strings got \"" + s + "\" for \"" + this.get('name') + "\"");
            this.set('value', s);
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this)); 
}
```

Comment: I am using ES6 arrow functions, it's like "Option 1". If you check the transcoded javascript (ES5).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem,
a thirdparty library changed the dom structure of
`{{u-button}}`..